# Alpha mask gradient on a uiimageview

Tags: objective-c, uiimageview, quartz-graphics, alpha

I'd like to be able to add an alpha gradient onto the edge of an image to make it "fade" into the next image. The picture below explains what I am trying to do.

[image: Example Picture]

Any idea on how to do this? I do not have much experience with the graphics context which is why I am here asking for help.

Comment: Hi, Did you figure out an answer to this question?  Stuck with a similar thing.

Comment: I did by manipulating the uiview's layer! Leave the bottom image (in this example, the right image) alone. Next, create a CAGradientLayer with positions at (in this example) [0,.95,1]. for colors, something like [white, white, clear] will do. next, set this layer as the mask for the uiimageview.

Answer (score -1):

You can check with this code and post the result.

```
UIImage* first = [[UIImage alloc]initWithContentsOfFile:@"firstImagePath"];
UIImage* second = [[UIImage alloc]initWithContentsOfFile:@"secondImagePath"];
CGSize sizeToSet;
int mergeArea = 200;
sizeToSet.width = first.size.width + second.size.width - mergeArea;
sizeToSet.height = first.size.height;

UIGraphicsBeginImageContext(sizeToSet);

[first drawAtPoint:CGPointMake(0, 0)];
[second drawAtPoint:CGPointMake(first.size.width - mergeArea, 0) blendMode:kCGBlendModeLuminosity alpha:1.0f];

UIImageView* imageView = [[UIImageView alloc]initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0, 0, 300, 300)];
[imageView setCenter:self.view.center];
[imageView setImage:UIGraphicsGetImageFromCurrentImageContext()];

UIGraphicsEndImageContext();

[[self view]addSubview:imageView];

[imageView release];
[first release];
[second release];
```

Comment: this solution didn't work. the images simply overlapped and the area where they were overlapping changed colors a bit. thanks for your comment though